# Css generated table breakpoint alternative to table-row

Tags: css

I have a table layout like:

```
<div style="display:table">
  <div style="display:table-row">
    <div style="display:table-cell">Content 1</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell">Content 2</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell">Content 3</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell">Content 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will properly show 4 columns in one row.

I want to have a media query that will show this table with 2 columns in each row.

For formatting reasons I need this to be a table and not a flexbox or a bootstrap grid.

Is there an alternative way to create breakpoints between cells so that an all css solution could be achieved?

Comment: display: table?

Comment: @IgorZinchenko As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) display table exist : _"These elements behave like HTML <table> elements. It defines a block-level box."_

Comment: If you use display:grid instead table, then you can get rid of the row container and reset the columns anytime

Comment: if you cant use <table> or display: table you can use float left and with or display inline-block and with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can switch display to another value with a mediaquerie

```
element {
  display: inline-block;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  element {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

quick example from your code , added var() to keep your style inline ...

```css
:root {
  --parent: table;
  --row: table-row;
  --cell: table-cell;
}

@media (max-width:800px) {
   :root {
    --row: grid;
    --cell: block;
  }
  [style="display:var(--row)"] {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto)
  }
}

body>* {
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px;
}

body> div>div>div, td {
  border: solid 1px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:var(--parent);">
  <div style="display:var(--row)">
    <div style="display:var(--cell)">Content 1</div>
    <div style="display:var(--cell)">Content 2</div>
    <div style="display:var(--cell)">Content 3</div>
    <div style="display:var(--cell)">Content 4 ---</div>
  </div>
</div>
Display:reset works for any HTML element, even if its an HTML table..
<table style="display:var(--parent);">
  <tr style="display:var(--row)">
    <td style="display:var(--cell)">Content 1</td>
    <td style="display:var(--cell)">Content 2</td>
    <td style="display:var(--cell)">Content 3</td>
    <td style="display:var(--cell)">Content 4 ---</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your suggestion to use grid was the way to go. In my media queries I use grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); to define exactly how many elements per row I want to show in each resolution